# The meaning of C L F Déposé on a French clock face

Tags: sens, acronymes

I have a vintage French clock with "CLF Déposé" written on the bottom of the face.
I would like to know what this means.
Thank you,

Comment: It doesn't mean anything obvious. Maybe an old brand? Your clock should be an advertising object.

Comment: Could you post an image?

Comment: According to the pictures we get on the web, [e.g](https://thumbs.worthpoint.com/zoom/images4/1/0316/28/antique-vintage-french-mantle-clock_1_4673cf42a41d98b94098d94076b7d91a.jpg) it's probably written *C.L.F. Déposé*. Since *déposé* means it is "registered" (as in registered trademark) C.L.F. must probably be the name of the makers and they have registered the model. Unless there's someone here who is well versed in antique clocks you'd be better off asking on a site specialised in antiques.

Answer (score 2):

Swiss are famous clockmakers.

If, as suggested by Laure in some OP's commentary, *Déposé* is an equivalent for ®*Registred*,

C.L.F. stands for a place, in particular here : **La Chaux-de-Fonds**

Comment: Well done! And according to [Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Chaux-de-Fonds#Les_d%C3%A9buts_de_l'horlogerie) watchmaking was important there. And [still is](https://www.dw.com/en/la-chaux-de-fonds-city-of-watchmakers/a-45343653).

Comment: I don't understand why CLF would bean La Chaux-de-Fonds since the letters do not match the name?! Can you explain it or give a reference?

Comment: I think CLF is a person, not a place. Specifically [C.L.F. Nicolet (or Nicollet)](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=yyx9CgAAQBAJ&pg=PT755&lpg=PT755&dq=%22c+l+f%22+chaux-de-fonds&source=bl&ots=tsnHz3tSKy&sig=ACfU3U1iHMX-WlDinGLo55c5e7t-ErqZew&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi42tbFlvnkAhXMTxUIHeUlADAQ6AEwAHoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22c%20l%20f%22%20chaux-de-fonds&f=false), who is from La Chaux-de-Fonds.

Comment: @LaurentG. : C(haux-de-fonds). L(ocle). (la)F(errière). Mais je reconnais m'être basé sur l'image suggérée par Laure qui peut ne pas être celle dont parle l'OP. L'image proposée montre le travail d'un *marchand* (un OEM on dirait aujourd'hui) qui indique les places de ses boutiques quand, comme c'est le cas ici, ces lieux sont emblématiques) Aujourd'hui, je crois que l'on met plutôt *Genève*... ça fait plus suisse sans doute... :-)